# Passed object not treated as the first parameter of function in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I call the function addToThis and pass in the obj the console.log(a) outputs the first array index value which is 1 instead of the obj why?

```
var obj = {num:2};

var addToThis = function(a,b){
  console.log(a);
  return this.num + a + b;
};

var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(addToThis.apply(obj,arr));
```

Comment: `apply` sends the contents of the array as individual arguments - so `a` will be set to `1`, and `b` set to `2`. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

When you use `apply()`, the first argument is the `this` argument, and the second argument is an array of arguments to be passed to the function. In your case, `a` is mapped to `1` and `b` is mapped to `2`. If you were to add a third argument, `c`, it would be mapped to `3`.

More simply put, the first argument in `apply()` is just what `this` will refer to in your function. The second argument is an array of arguments that get passed to the function.

If you were to add `console.log(this)` you would see your object.

```js
var obj = {num:2};

var addToThis = function(a,b){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(this);
  return this.num + a + b;
};

var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(addToThis.apply(obj,arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it from what I understand. The syntax for using apply is:

```
fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
```

Here, thisArg states the context which will be applied to function. (Eg, this). [argsArray] is the array of arguments to the function.

When you do this:

```
addToThis.apply(obj,arr)
```

you're basically passing `arr=[1,2,3]` as the arguments to your addToThis function. Thus, `a` becomes 1, `b` becomes 2, if you had a `c` in your function definition, that would be 3..and so on till it reaches the length of your array.

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3cnvxxkx/) fiddle, here `console.log(c)` prints out the third element in your array. But, if you wrote this code:

```
var obj = {num:2};

var addToThis = function(a,b,c,d){
  console.log(a);   //prints first element in array
  console.log(b);   //prints second element
  console.log(c);   //prints third element
  console.log(d);   //prints undefined because there is no forth element 
};

var arr = [1,2,3];
addToThis.apply(obj,arr);
```

Hope this helps.